# Custom Module to remove User Menu Tabs

Tags: navigation

I'm hoping someone can take pity on me because I just can't seem to figure out how to make a simple module to remove, or hide some tabs in my user pages.
I read the docs on making custom modules, questions about removing tabs, and thought I figured it out. I made a custom module called 'TabEdit' with this structure, just to test it out:

/tabedit

```
    tabedit.info.yml
    tabedit.module
```

tabedit.info.yml

```
name: TabEdit
description: Edit tabs shown in user pages.
type: module
package: custom
core: 8.x
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
```

tabedit.module

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()
 */
function tabedit_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {
  unset($data['tabs'][0]['simplenews.newsletter_subscriptions_user']);
}
```

It didn't work, so I obviously still don't get the fundamentals on how to make a module. What I want to do is remove the Shortcuts, Simplenews Subscriptions, Activity, and Submissions from the user menu tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Hooks need to be written in . module file not in controller. Move your code to .module file and also it should be tabedit_menu_local_tasks_alter

**tabedit.module**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()
 */
function tabedit_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {
  unset($data['tabs'][0]['simplenews.newsletter_subscriptions_user']);
}
```

- Clear flush all caches so hook gets pickedup.

Comment: So I would take what was in the php file and move it to a tabedit.module file? If that's the case, do I need anything in the Controller folder?

Comment: @TomP no Controller folder needed.

Comment: I had made those changes. I just edited my original question to match. My user tabs still has NEWSLETTERS (/user/2/simplenews). I've also flushed the cache after reinstalling each time. I'm hoping if this can work I can use it to get rid of a couple other tabs as well.

Comment: @TomP file name should be tabedit.module not RemoveTabEdit.php

Comment: Sorry. I edited the original question to match what I've been trying

Answer (score 1):

A file like src/Controller/RemoveTabEdit.php is for a class, not a function. In the specific, it's not for hook implementations, which should always go in the module file.

The src/Controller/RemoveTabEdit.php file is automatically loaded when the `RemoveTabEdit` class is used, but since that doesn't happen, the file is never loaded and that hook implementation is never found.

As side note, it's better to avoid uppercase characters in the module machine name. While PHP is case insensitive, the code looking for `hook_update_N()` implementations is still case sensitive.

Comment: Ok that starts to make sense. So what would the structure look like. Doesn't a .module file have to go in the root of the module? Also what would the php file need to do then?

Comment: If you don't have any code for that file, that file can simply be removed. Yes, the *tabedit.module* file goes in the directory containing the *tabedit.info.yml* file.

Comment: I've now have a single folder 'tabedit' with two files the 'tabedit.info.yml' and 'tabedit.module'. I completely removed the src folder.

The .module file only has the one function I'm using to test

<?php
'function tabedit_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {
 unset($data['tabs'][0]['simplenews.newsletter_subscriptions_user']);
}'
It's still not working. If the module is correct maybe the tab address is wrong.

Comment: If you edit a module code after it has been installed, Drupal doesn't notice the code has been changed, or new files have been added. You need to uninstall the module and re-install it. Any code change must be done when the module isn't installed. As for the SimpleNews module, it has a [*simplenews.newsletter_subscriptions_user*](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/simplenews/-/blob/8.x-2.x/simplenews.links.task.yml#L51) tab; that is correct.

Comment: In particular, Drupal keeps in cache the list of hooks implemented from modules. The only way to refresh that cache is installing or uninstalling a module.

Comment: Yes I did uninstall, edit, then install. I got the address from the same file as you pointed out so I was sure it was right. My user tabs still has NEWSLETTERS (/user/2/simplenews). I've also flushed the cache after reinstalling each time. I just don't know what I could still be missing. This should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

This did finally works. I renamed it tabedit.module and made the code

```
<?php
/**
  * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
  */
function tabedit_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {
/*      If a current user has the 'administrator' role then do not hide the tabs.
    $current_user_roles = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
    if (in_array('administrator', $current_user_roles)) {
        return;
    }
*/      
    unset($data['tabs'][0]['tracker.user_tab']);
    unset($data['tabs'][0]['shortcut.set_switch']);
    unset($data['tabs'][0]['simplenews.newsletter_subscriptions_user']);
    unset($data['tabs'][0]['entity.webform_submission.user']);
}
``
```